# PHP: access static member of class from instance in local class member

Tags: php

I'd like do do this:

```
class A {
    public static $var = 'foo';
}

class B {
    private $a;

    public function __construct($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function f() {
        echo $this->a::$var; // <---- ERROR
        echo get_class($this->a)::$var; // <---- ERROR

        // WORKING but awful
        $a = $this->a;
        echo $a::$var;
    }
}

$b = new B(new A());
$b->f();
```

Note that I don't know if `$a` is an instance of `A` or another class, I just know that it has a static `$var` member. So, unfortunately, I can't use `A::$var` inside `f`.

Does anyone know if there is a single-expression syntax to do this, using PHP 5.3+?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Sorry can't do that, see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an instance of A into B, but $var is a static Member of A which can only be accessed using :: like A::$var.

```
private function f() {
    echo A::$var;
}
```

EDIT:
if you want to make it dependant of the instance stored in $a you could do something like:

```
public function f() {
    $class = get_class($this->a);
    echo $class::$var;
}
```

Comment: See the comment in rid's answer, unfortunately I can't do that

Comment: I editted my answer to point out the usage of get_class() http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-class.php

Comment: Unfortunately the `get_class` approach doesn't work, I get the following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: See my Edit. It's phpish stuff with chaining things. Store the get_class result to a variable. Now its working. And don't forget to set f() to public as you are accessing it from outside

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with a similar working approach that doesn't require `get_class`. Anyway it's pretty redundant to have to store a local member in a local variable in order to use the static access syntax. There must be a single-expression syntax to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'm seeing is that you couldn't call f() as it is private.

```
$b->f();
```

Then maybe you can turn to something like this?

```
class B extends A{
    private $a;

    public function __construct($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function f() {
        echo static::$var;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right about the `private` access, it was a typo. I've edited the question and added a working but ugly approach.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work but I'd question why you'd want to do this:

```
class A {
    public static $var = 'foo';
}

class B {
    private $a;

    public function __construct($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function f() {
        if ($this->a instanceof A) {
            echo A::$var;
        }
    }
}

$b = new B(new A());
$b->f();
```

you don't need to do anything specifically with $this->a as $var is static to the class.

Comment: I've updated the question, I'm actually wondering if there's a single-expression syntax to do this.

Comment: My concern for using this without the instanceof check is that you have no guarantee that the class of the object $a has a static public variable $var.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function like so:

```
function get_static_property($class, $property) {
    return $class::$$property;
}
```

I can't help but wonder why you would need this. Any reason why you can't have A implement an interface? Or use a trait?
That way you can just echo `$this->a->someMethodName()`.

PS. returning strings is generally preferred over echoing inside methods.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over `A` whatsoever, it's implemented in an external library, and the library decides what to pass to `B`'s constructor. The only guarantee that I have is that `$a` has a static `$var` member.

Comment: I am guessing you need $this->a for more then just getting the value of static $var, is this correct?

Comment: Ok, that eliminates something I was thinking about then. I assume the ugly local variable is better for performance, but calling the above function is cleaner IMHO. That is all I have for you, good luck.